# Cómo usar except ValueError y confirmacion para entrar a una opción

Tags: python, excepciones

Ojala me pudieran ayudar, ya que no se cómo implementar el `except ValueError` para que mi programa no acepte valores incorrectos.

Otra cosa que no se muy bien, seria que al entrar a alguna opción preguntara si desea entrar en dicha opción, esto es por si algún motivo se equivocara en una opción así no se entraría y se quedaría en el menú.

El programa ya funciona solo seria hacerlo contra errores por eso mismo del `except valueError`

```
import os   

class Lista:

    def __init__(self):
        self.Inicio = None
        self.Fin = None 
        self.Temp = None

    def Añadir(self,Dato1):

        mNodo = Nodo(Dato1,0)
        if (self.Inicio == None):
            self.Inicio = mNodo
        else:
            self.Fin.Siguiente = mNodo
            self.Fin = self.Fin.Siguiente
        self.Fin = mNodo

    def Eliminar(self,Nodo3,NodoActual):

        self.Temp = Nodo3
        self.Temp.Siguiente = NodoActual.Siguiente  

    def Insertar(self,Nodo2,Dato3):

        mNodo = Nodo(Dato3,0)
        self.Temp = Nodo2.Siguiente
        Nodo2.Siguiente = mNodo
        mNodo.Siguiente = self.Temp

class Nodo:

    def __init__(self, Dato1, Dato2):

        self.Dato1 = Dato1
        self.Dato2 = Dato2
        self.Siguiente = None
#Clase
class Interfaz:

    def Procedimientos(self):

        Nombre = input("Nombre del archivo: ")

        print ("\t1 - Ingresar Numeros: ")
        print ("\t2 - Lectura: ")
        print ("\t3 - Modificar: ")     

        while True:     

            Menu = int(input("Selecciona una opción: "))

            if Menu == 1:           

                Archivo = open(Nombre,'a')
                NumValores = float(input("Total de valores a ingresar: "))

                Cont = 0
                while (Cont < NumValores):
                    Datos = input("ingresa un  valor: ")
                    float(Datos)
                    Archivo.write(Datos + "\n" )    
                    Cont = Cont + 1
                Archivo.close()         

            elif Menu == 2:

                Archivo = open(Nombre, "r")
                for Linea in Archivo.readlines():
                    print(Linea)
                Archivo.close()

            elif Menu == 3:

                Archivo = open(Nombre,'r')
                mLista = Lista()

                for linea in Archivo:
                    num = float(linea)
                    mLista.Añadir(num)
                Archivo.close()

                mNodo = mLista.Inicio
                mFin = mLista.Fin

                while (mNodo != None):
                    print(mNodo.Dato1)

                    print ("\t1 - Aceptar Valor")
                    print ("\t2 - Remplazar")
                    print ("\t3 - Añadir")
                    print ("\t4 - Eliminar")
                    print ("\t5 - Aceptar Todos Los Valores") 
                    print ("\t6 - Guardar")

                    SubMenu = int(input("Selecciona una Opcion: "))

                    if SubMenu == 1:

                        mNodo = mNodo.Siguiente

                    elif SubMenu == 2:

                        RempNum = float(input("ingresa el nuevo Numero: "))
                        mNodo.Dato1 = RempNum
                        mNodo = mNodo.Siguiente

                    elif SubMenu == 3:

                        X = 0
                        while (X != 2):
                            NumInsert = float(input("ingresa el nuevo valor: "))
                            nNodo = Nodo(NumInsert,0)
                            self.Temp = mNodo.Siguiente
                            mNodo.Siguiente = nNodo
                            nNodo.Siguiente =self.Temp
                            mNodo=nNodo 
                            X = int(input("insertar otro numero: 1 = si / 2 = no: "))
                        mNodo = mNodo.Siguiente 

                    elif SubMenu == 4:  

                        mNodo.Dato1 = -1
                        mNodo = mNodo.Siguiente

                    elif SubMenu == 5:

                        break

                    else:

                        break

                Guardar = int(input("conservar el nombre del archivo 1 = si / 2 = no: "))

                if Guardar == 2:
                    Nombre=input("Nuevo nombre: ")
                mnNodo= mLista.Inicio

                Archivo = open(Nombre,'w')
                while (mnNodo != None ):
                    if mnNodo.Dato1 > -1:
                        print(mnNodo.Dato1)
                        Archivo.write(str(mnNodo.Dato1))
                        Archivo.write("\n")
                    mnNodo = mnNodo.Siguiente
                Archivo.close()

class Main:

    def __init__(self):
        self.mInterfaz = Interfaz()
        self.mInterfaz.Procedimientos()
Main()
```

Comment: Creo que debes ser más específico en el código y no solo copiar todo, dónde lo quieres meter? etc, para mejor ayuda

Comment: disculpa creo si debí especificar mas, quisiera poder implementar esa función en todos los input donde pido ingresar numeros o datos

Answer (score 0):

Son hartos `input()` así que más que dar una conversión de todo el código voy a dar dos ideas que puedes implementar en varias partes del código, aunque probablemente una reestructuración sea necesaria para que quede mejor que "parcharlo".

Una opción genérica de ver este problema es dejar el `try/except` dentro de un `while True`

```
while True:
    try:
        var = int(input('Ingrese un entero'))
        break
    except ValueError:
        print('No es un número entero. Volveremos a intentarlo')
```

de manera que mientras entre al `except` siempre vuelva a realizar la consulta y si termina exitosamente rompe el `while` y continúa con el código.

Para aterrizarlo en el código veamos que pasa con `NumValores`:

```
if Menu == 1:           
    Archivo = open(Nombre,'a')
    NumValores = float(input("Total de valores a ingresar: "))
    Cont = 0
```

Con la modificación quedaría:

```
if Menu == 1:           
    Archivo = open(Nombre,'a')
    while True:
        try:
            NumValores = float(input("Total de valores a ingresar: "))
            break
        except ValueError:
            print("Se pedía un número en coma flotante. Volvamos a intentarlo")
    Cont = 0
```

Sencillo ¿no? Por ahora sí, pero que pasa con `Menu`?

```
while True:
    Menu = int(input("Selecciona una opción: "))
    if Menu == 1:
        print("Hacer 1) ...")
    elif Menu == 2:
        print("Hacer 2) ...")
    elif Menu == 3:
        print("Hacer 3) ...")
    else
        print("Saliendo...")
        break
```

Ya está incluido el `while True`. Si bien puedes incluir un nuevo `while`, es innecesario pero tenemos que modificar el `break` de otro modo se saldría del menú con un valor válido. Veamos:

```
while True:
    try: 
        Menu = int(input("Selecciona una opción: "))
    except ValueError:
        print("Se pedía un número entero. Volvamos a intentarlo")
        continue
    if Menu == 1:
        print("Hacer 1) ...")
    elif Menu == 2:
        print("Hacer 2) ...")
    elif Menu == 3:
        print("Hacer 3) ...")
    else
        print("Saliendo...")
        break
```

En este caso, es el `except` el que reinicia el loop al hacer un `continue`.

Lo interesante de todo esto es que con una pequeña modificación extra puedes verificar que los valores ingresados estén dentro de un rango aceptable ¿Qué pasaría si NumValores es 10000?, pero eso es tarea para la casa.

PS: ¿Es necesario que `NumValores` sea de tipo float?